# Flutter Firebase Stripe issue with json.decode

Tags: firebase, flutter, stripe-payments

I try to implement Stripe on my Flutter Firebase project but I've got an issue.

Here's my code :

```
Future<void> makePayment () async {
final url = Uri.parse('***********');

final response = await http.get(url,
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});

paymentIntentData = json.decode(response.body);
// Here's the issue

await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
  paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
    paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData!['paymentIntent'],
    applePay: true,
    googlePay: true,
    style: ThemeMode.dark,
    merchantCountryCode: 'US',
    merchantDisplayName: 'Test',
  )
);
setState(() {
  
});

displayPaymentSheet();
  }
```

Got this error :

```
FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
Error: could not handle the request
^
)
```

I've tried to search the reason it returns this error, but can not find. Please someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong ? I don't want bother you with too much code, if you need anything to help me understand where is my mistake, just let me know.

Comment: please share your response data

Comment: It's already shared: 

final response = await http.get(url,
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can check the Logs in Stripe Dashboard https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs and see if the Payment Intent is created successfully.

Comment: Yes it is, but the field "application" is null, maybe this is the issue ?